# Où entend-on le « beding-bedang », entend-on autre chose etc. ?

Tags: québec, origine-ou-raison, régionalismes, onomatopées

> « Les premiers temps, il [ un paraplégique qui se déplace avec des
> cannes ] tombait partout » [ ... ]. « On était au restaurant et on
> entendait beding bedang. On se disait : Voilà André qui arrive. » ([ds.](https://www.bdlp.org/resultat?base=QU&query=400376,0) L'Actualité, 1986)

> [...] il se revoit glisser sur une plaque de glace, beding, bedang,
> face première, maudit hiver, il se revoit nettoyer ses mains souillées
> dans un banc de neige… (ds. [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/2021-03-14/la-fille-de-la-bande-annonce.php), 2021)

---

- Dans la francophonie, connaît-on l'onomatopée familière québécoise «
  [beding-bedang](https://www.bdlp.org/resultat?base=QU&query=400376,0) » pour « exprimer le bruit répété de ce qui chute,
  de ce qui est manipulé sans ménagement, projeté dans tous les sens »
  (BDLP) ?
- A-t-on une onomatopée équivalente ou employée dans le même genre de
  contexte  ?
- Les onomatopées varient-elles dans les régions où l'on parle français
  de la même manière que le lexique ou y a-t-il une explication
  générale de la variation des onomatopées d'une région à l'autre ou
  c'est toujours du cas par cas et incidemment entend-on la réalité
  différemment d'une région à l'autre ?

Comment: Beding-bedang est inconnu de moi (France). Je pense à vlan, (vling vlan pour la répétition), bing bang (bing et bang)

Comment: @None — ***Badaboum, patatras*** sont des onomatopées usuelles pour les chutes.

Answer (score 1):

- Non, je dirais que "beding-bedang" n'existe pas, en France tout du
  moins.
- Dans le cas du second exemple l'on aurait utilisé "boum badaboum".

> Les onomatopées varient-elles dans les régions où l'on parle français de la même manière que le lexique...

Oui.

> y a-t-il une explication générale de la variation des onomatopées d'une région à l'autre

Pas à ma connaissance. Les mêmes raisons qui expliquent les variations du langage lui-même j'imagine.

> ou c'est toujours du cas par cas et incidemment entend-on la réalité différemment d'une région à l'autre ?

Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre "entend-on la réalité différemment"...

Comment: Merci. Je voulais dire est-ce que le fait d'avoir des onomatopées différentes signifient qu'on perçoive la réalité différemment. Finalement est-ce que beding bedang et boum badaboum sont si différents, en fait les deux ont deux éléments avec des sons en « b » et c'est seulement la finale qui diffère.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille "beding bedang" sonne métallique, ça évoque des casseroles, de la ferraille; "badaboum" est plus sourd, et évoque une masse lourde qui tombe et roule. C'était juste mes deux sous :-)

Comment: Je ne saurais répondre à cette question... Pas mieux que @wazoox en tout cas :)
Subjectivement je dirais que du moment que l'on met une onomatopée sur quelque chose (bruit, action...) c'est pour exprimer un ressenti qui a de fortes chances d'être identique, donc une perception de la réalité relativement proche oui.